# Request microphone permission in electron

Tags: javascript, electron, user-permissions

I have an electron app that uses the webkit speech recognition API. If tested in the browser, everything works as intended, but if run in the electron environment, the speech recognition api doesn't work.

What I mean is that when I press the button that starts the recording, the recording won't start in the electron environment. I believe that is because unlike when running the code in the browser, I wasn't asked for and therefore not granted microphone access. So my question is then, how can I request access for the microphone in an electron app? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this in the electron docs.
https://electronjs.org/docs/api/system-preferences#systempreferencesaskformediaaccessmediatype-macos

If you're using macOS to run the app use that method to request permission. If not it doesn't look like the app requires permission to use the microphone or camera.

Comment: This is the opposite problem on non-Macs when you are building a web browser type of application. It poses a great security risk as a website can basically eavesdrop on the user, without requesting additional permissions. (at the moment I'm searching for the solution)